# What is Delayed Hyper Combo (DHC)?

Tags: terminology, ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3, marvel-vs-capcom-3

In, I believe Marvel vs. Capcom 3 and Ultimate Marvel vs. Capcom 3, there is something called the DHC glitch which stands for Delayed Hyper Combo. What is it exactly?

Comment: Note that the glitch existed in MvC3, but [it was removed in UMvC3](http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2011/jul/20/early-impressions-floe-others-umvc3-dhc-glitch-gone/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DHC itself isn't a glitch; it just involves canceling one character's Hyper move animation into a second character's Hyper by inputting the commands for the second character's hyper (for example, Quartercircle Forward + 2 Attack buttons). The first character's Hyper will abruptly be canceled into the second character's Hyper. There's a time window when you can do this, usually around before the final hit in the first Hyper combo. Note that not all Hypers DHC into eachother cleanly; some will almost always miss when chained together.

The DHC "glitch" is something different from DHC itself; a DHC is a completely intended gameplay mechanic (which is used in other games such as Skullgirls). The DHC glitch involves using a DHC move that you're sure will miss, which will end your combo/hitstun in order to reset damage scaling. I'm not sure it's really a glitch, it's just a peculiar sort of Reset used to reset damage scaling (it's been removed in Ultimate though, so maybe it was a glitch). I can't word it much better than [Chacronic in this GameFAQs thread:](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/637240-/60716441)

> When you use a hyper then tag in someone else for another hyper combo aka a DHC that will deliberately miss (Think Taskmaster/Wesker's counters or Wolvies Beserker charge hyper combos) so you get a reset in damage and can start up a new combo. This will usually result in far more damage then just doing a delayed hyper combo and usually killing an opponent in a single combo string.

Here's a video of it:

Note that the DHC reset trick [was removed in Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3](http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2011/jul/20/early-impressions-floe-others-umvc3-dhc-glitch-gone/) so it might have been a glitch afterall. Either way it's MVC3 only.

Comment: So "glitch" is a misnomer? I wonder how it came about if it was always intended. It sounds like this started out as a glitch and became an Ascended Glitch.

Comment: @NiteCyper lots of fighting game mechanics started out as glitches, it's hard to call the line where some things are glitches or are intended; the DHC reset trick was removed in Ultimate though (updated answer) so it's likely it was either a glitch or unintentionally powerful.

Comment: Ah, so missing any hit of a DHC used to break a combo as the GAME recognizes a combo and counts hits, regardless of whether or not the opponent could escape?

Comment: @NiteCyper The fact that it reset damage scaling made the technique extremely powerful and character specific, so it affected the overall balance of the game (yes, I realize that this is a strange thing to say with Marvel).